# WPF - allow user to define hotkeys

Tags: wpf, vb.net, tabs

Is it possible to allow the user to define their own hotkeys?  I tried this code but it broke all the other hotkeys that I have programmatically defined.  And Alt-P did not work as expected either:

```
        Dim strHotKey As String = "Key." & "P"

    ProjectCustomerInfoTab_HotKey.InputGestures.Add(New KeyGesture(CType(strHotKey, Key), ModifierKeys.Alt))
```

My thinking was to present the user with a combobox and allow them to choose the letter to be used for the hotkey.  In this case, "P" (for now, just pretend the "P" was selected in the combobox).

I have other command bindings and they no longer function if I use the above syntax.  If I change it back to ProjectCustomerInfoTab_HotKey.InputGestures.Add(New KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Alt)), then the hot key functionality returns.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to suply a Key enum value to KeyGesture constructor.
In order to do so just parse the string input to obtain needed enum value:

```
    var userInput = "G";
    Key k;
    if (Key.TryParse(userInput, out k)) {
        Grid.InputBindings.Add(new InputBinding(AsyncCommand, new KeyGesture(k, ModifierKeys.Control)));
    };
```

VB Code:

```
Dim userInput As Object = "P" Dim k As Key 
If Key.TryParse(CStr(userInput), k) Then  
  ProjectCustomerInfoTab_HotKey.InputGestures.Add(New KeyGesture(k, ModifierKeys.Alt))
  tabctlInformation.CommandBindings.Add(New CommandBinding(ProjectCustomerInfoTab_HotKey, AddressOf Me.ProjectCustomerInfoTab))
End If
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked very well.  If anyone else is a vb'er, here's the translated code:          Dim userInput As Object = "P"
        Dim k As Key
        If Key.TryParse(CStr(userInput), k) Then
            ProjectCustomerInfoTab_HotKey.InputGestures.Add(New KeyGesture(k, ModifierKeys.Alt))
            tabctlInformation.CommandBindings.Add(New CommandBinding(ProjectCustomerInfoTab_HotKey, AddressOf Me.ProjectCustomerInfoTab))
        End If

Comment: @EManning I've added your comment to the answer, not sure if it's formatted well. Feel free to edit it if needed.